# Numerical integration: Solve upper bound given integral

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

Given the answer L to the integral of a function f(x), how can I solve for the upper bound b using numerical integration?

$$\displaystyle \int_0^{b} f(x) dx = L$$

The anti-derivative of f(x) is of course not trivially solvable (unless I've missed something - in my case it is the square root of a quartic function)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Comment: Just for your curiosity : $\int \sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}\,dx$ has a closed form (it is just a monster with a buch of elliptic integrals).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh wow! not worth going down that root at all then? The goal is an efficient computer algorithm?

Comment: Yes I know !  Back to serious,you could use higher order methods such  as Halley or Householder. This is what I should do since you have the higher order derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve $F(b) = L$ for $b$ with $$F(b) = \int_0^bf(x)\,dx\,.$$
There are many methods to numerically solve an equation. As you know the derivative of $F$, I would suggest [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Given a starting guess $b_0$, you simply iterate
$$b_{n+1} = b_n - \frac{F(b_n)}{F'(b_n)}=b_n - \frac{1}{f(b_n)} \left(\int_0^{b_n}f(x)\,dx -L\right)\,.$$

Comment: Just implemented this in code and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GaryAllen: How are you estimating the error $b-b_n(h)$? The limit $b_\infty(h)$ of the Newton sequence is a function of the step size $h$ used to compute approximations of the integrals.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, but I've used Simpson's rule to compute the integral itself, with a Newton's method function calling this integral and subtracting L from it each time it wishes to determine F(bn) @CarlChristian

Comment: @GaryAllen Then you are on the right path. However, the number that you have obtained depends on the step size that you used for Simpson's rule. I propose that you investigate the effect of using different number of subintervals, say, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160. You will get a slightly different value of $b$ from each experiment. It is likely that we will be able to use Richardson's techniques and extrapolate to the limit where the integrals are evaluated exactly.

Comment: @CarlChristian I've fortunately catered for that already - I use an algorithm from a book I own which computes the integral based on tolerance instead of step size (increasing the step size one by one to "refine" the answer) so the answer is definitive each time, and is always accurate within tolerance

Comment: @GaryAllen. This sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are actually many ways of estimate your integral, provided that it is typical Riemann integral, you can use the Trapezoidal rule, Simpson's rule, Gauss quadrature. Wikipedia has info, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule but it is better if you consults a book on numerical analysis.

For example refer to section 3.2 of Numerical Analysis Walter Gautschi.
https://books.google.co.cr/books?id=-fgjJF9yAIwC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Another method that does not require you to recompute all the work if your guess for $b$ was not accurate enough is following. Consider some grid $x_n = n h$ with stepsize $h$. Do the following steps
$$
J_0 = 0\\
J_{n+1} = J_n + \int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}} f(x) dx.
$$
Here $J(x)$ is simply $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ and $J_n = J(x_n)$.

You may use any **single-interval** quadrature that you like, no need to split interval $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$ into smaller pieces.

After each step check that $J_{n+1} < L$. If it is not true, then you've localized $b$ in the $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$ interval. Indeed, $J(x_n) < L$ (otherwise you would stop at the previous step) and $J(x_{n+1}) \geq L$. The solution of the
$$
J(b) = L
$$
should be somewhere between the $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$.

Now you need to solve
$$
\int_{x_n}^b f(x) dx = L - J_n.
$$
The interval $b - x_n$ is small (less than $h$) and you have a decent initial guess, that can be derived from a linear approximation:
$$
\frac{b_0 - x_n}{x_{n+1} - x_n} = \frac{L - J_n}{J_{n+1} - J_{n}}
$$

Let's approximate $\int_{x_n}^b f(x) dx$ with some quadrature formula with weights $w_i$ and abscissae $\xi_i \in [0, 1]$:
$$
\int_{x_n}^b f(x) dx \approx (b-x_n) \sum_{i=0}^M w_i f(x_n + \xi_i (b - x_n))
$$
Rewriting the equation in $F(b) = 0$ form we have:
$$
F(b) = J_n + (b-x_n)\sum_{i=0}^M w_i f(x_n + \xi_i (b - x_n)) - L = 0\\
F'(b) = \sum_{i=0}^M w_i f(x_n + \xi_i (b - x_n)) + (b - x_n)
\sum_{i=0}^M w_i \xi_i f'(x_n + \xi_i (b - x_n))
$$
and the Newton iterations for this equation will be
$$
b_{k+1} = b_{k} - \frac{F(b_k)}{F'(b_k)}.
$$
If exact value for $F'(b)$ is hard to compute, $F'(b) \approx f(b)$ can be used instead.